# Filter DataGrid columns and pass object to ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I get this error :

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'OpenPopupCommand' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=62725275)'. BindingExpression:Path=OpenPopupCommand; DataItem='String'

when I added a parameter to my command:

```
OpenPopupCommand = new RelayParamCommand((e) => PopupVisibility(FilterButton) );
```

VM:

```
private void PopupVisibility(object sender)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sender.ToString());
    PopupVisible ^= true;
}
```

Think is that I added Filter Button to Datagrid Headers which are generated automatically. Now I want to open popup when button is clicked. But think is that is not working, because i have to pass button by buttons x:Name to Popup PlacementTarget parameter.

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <PDB:UsersViewModel x:Name="vm"/>
</Page.DataContext>


<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--Page Header info content-->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding ElementName=userPage, Path=Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding SelectedUser.Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding ElementName=myGrd, Path=CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex}"/>
            <Button x:Name="mybtn" 
                    Content="{Binding Filters.Count, Mode=OneWay}" 
                    Visibility="{Binding Filters.Count, Converter={Wpf:VisibilityConverter}}" 
                    />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <!--Datagrid content-->
    <DataGrid x:Name="myGrd" 

              SelectionMode="Single"    
              SelectionUnit="Cell"
              CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}"
              CurrentColumn="{Binding CurrentColumn, Mode=TwoWay}"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              Grid.Row="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredUserList}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="True"             
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              >
        <DataGrid.Resources>

            <!--Popup-->
            <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu">
                <ContextMenu.Items>
                    <MenuItem Header="Filter by Selection" Command="{Binding IncludeCommand, Source={x:Reference vm}}"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Filter exclude Selection" Command="{Binding ExcludeCommand, Source={x:Reference vm}}"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Remove all Filters" Command="{Binding RemoveAllFiltersCommand, Source={x:Reference vm}}" Visibility="{Binding Filters.Count, Source={x:Reference vm}, Converter={Wpf:VisibilityConverter}}"/>
                </ContextMenu.Items>
            </ContextMenu>

            <!--Custom Datagrid header View-->               
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" x:Name="FilterHeader">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBox Margin="0,0,0,10" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}, Path=Width}" />
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Button Name="FilterButton" 
                                            Content="[-F-]" 
                                            Command="{Binding OpenPopupCommand}" 
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=FilterButton}"/>
                                    <Popup Name="MyPopup" 
                                           StaysOpen="False" 
                                           Placement="Right" 
                                           IsOpen="{Binding PopupVisible}"
                                           PlacementTarget="{Binding FilterButton}">
                                        <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" Padding="5" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Popup> 
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

By this approach i want to pass clicked button  as parameter to VM  and bind it to Popup PlacementTarget parameter.  What i am doing wrong?  Can i pass clicked button parameter? I know i break mvvm rules when passing view to vm, but how to achieve what i want, when i don't want to define every column in datagrid. Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do xou think you need to pass the `Button` to the view model? Do you only wont to ope nthe `Popup` when the `Button` is clicked?

Comment: Yes but the problem is i need identify in what column button was or what button, because in popup i want to implement filter to choose filter values which are in that column. I would implement that easy if i define columns, but i dont want to go that way.

Comment: You are specifying a template which will apply to all column headers. The `Button` is not specific enough to identify the column. What you need is the header content which is the name of the property the column binds to. What exactly do you want to display in the `Popup`?

Comment: checkbox list of all values in that column, that user can select them and filter. Same as excel filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bindings have the `DataContext` of the `DataGridColumnHeader` as source which  is the value of `DataGridColumn.Header`. This value in your case is a `string` and not your expected view model. This is the reason why your bindings doesn't resolve and you get the error message (which is exactly telling you this).

To fix the binding you have to find the next parent element that has the required `DataContext`, which is I assume the `DataGrid`:

```
<Button Name="FilterButton" 
        Content="[-F-]" 
        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.OpenPopupCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

When checking your code I can see the command which is bound to the `Button` is *toggling* the `PopupVisible` property. I therefore suggest to remove this view related code from the view model and replace the `Button` with a `ToggleButton` which binds directly to the `Popup.IsOpen`:

```
 <!--Custom Datagrid header View-->
  <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
      <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Margin="0,0,0,10"
                     Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}, Path=Width}" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
              <ToggleButton Name="FilterButton"
                            Content="[-F-]" />
              <Popup Name="MyPopup"
                     StaysOpen="False"
                     Placement="Right"
                     IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=FilterButton, Path=IsChecked}"
                     PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=FilterButton}">
                <Border Background="White"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        Padding="5"
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        CornerRadius="5">
                  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                  </StackPanel>
                </Border>
              </Popup>
            </StackPanel>
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

To get the cell values of all rows contained in a single column where the column header value is the parameter and maps to a property name requires reflection. You need to bind a `ListView` to the resulting column value collection which uses an `ItemTemplate` to add a `CheckBox` to the item. The final version should be as follows:

```
<!--Custom Datagrid header View-->
<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
  <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBox Margin="0,0,0,10"
                   Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}, Path=Width}" />
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <ToggleButton Name="FilterButton"
                          Content="[-F-]"
                          Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.(UsersViewModel.GenerateFilterViewItemsCommand)}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridColumnHeader}, Path=Content}" />
            <Popup Name="MyPopup"
                   StaysOpen="False"
                   Placement="Right"
                   IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=FilterButton, Path=IsChecked}"
                   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=FilterButton}">
              <Border Background="White"
                      BorderBrush="Black"
                      Padding="5"
                      BorderThickness="2"
                      CornerRadius="5">
                <ListView
                  ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.(UsersViewModel.FilterViewItems)}">
                  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsIncluded, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                                  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.(UsersViewModel.IncludeItemCommand)}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CellValue}" />
                      </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
              </Border>
            </Popup>
          </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

To map the filter list to the actual items requires an additional type to hold the information:

**Predicate.cs**

```
public class FilterPredicate
{
  public FilterPredicate(int rowIndex, object cellValue, object columnKey)
  {
    this.RowIndex = rowIndex;
    this.CellValue = cellValue;
    this.ColumnKey = columnKey;
  }

  public int RowIndex { get; set; }
  public object CellValue { get; set; }
  public bool IsIncluded { get; set; }
  public object ColumnKey { get; set; }
}
```

You also need to add a collection for the filter view and one for the included item indices to the view model:

**UsersViewModel.cs**

```
public class UsersViewModel
{
  public UsersViewModel()
  {
    this.FilterViewItems = new ObservableCollection<FilterPredicate>();
    this.IncludedItemsIndex = new Dictionary<object, List<int>>();
  }

  // The binding source for the Popup filter view
  public ObservableCollection<FilterPredicate> FilterViewItems { get; set; } 
  private Dictionary<object, List<int>> IncludedItemsIndex { get; set; }      

  public ICommand GenerateFilterViewItemsCommand => new RelayParamCommand((param) =>
  {
    var columnHeader = param as string;
    this.IncludedItemsIndex.Remove(columnHeader);
    this.FilterViewItems.Clear();
    for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < this.FilteredUserList.Count; rowIndex++)
    {
      var data = this.FilteredUserList.ElementAt(rowIndex);
      var columnValue = data.GetType()
        .GetProperty(columnHeader, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)?
        .GetValue(data);

      if (columnValue != null)
      {
        this.FilterViewItems.Add(new FilterPredicate(rowIndex, columnValue, columnValue));
      }
    }
  });

  public ICommand IncludeItemCommand => new RelayParamCommand((param) =>
  {
    var predicate = param as FilterPredicate;
    if (predicate.IsIncluded)
    {
      if (!this.IncludedItemsIndex.TryGetValue(predicate.ColumnKey, out List<int> includedIndices))
      {
        includedIndices = new List<int>();
        this.IncludedItemsIndex.Add(predicate.ColumnKey, includedIndices);
      }

      includedIndices.Add(predicate.RowIndex);
    }
    else
    {
      if (this.IncludedItemsIndex.TryGetValue(predicate.ColumnKey, out List<int> includedIndices))
      {
        includedIndices.Remove(predicate.RowIndex);
      }
    }

    // Apply the filter
    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.FilteredUserList).Filter =
      data => this.IncludedItemsIndex.Values
        .SelectMany(indices => indices)
        .Contains(this.FilteredUserList.IndexOf(data as FilteredUser));
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and amazing answer, but could you explain this line : Path=DataContext.(viewModels:TestViewModel.GenerateFilterViewItemsCommand)  what it does? I have to pass view model to datacontext?

Comment: Sorry, I had a few renaming errors (`Predicate` -> `FilterPredicate` was one of them). I hope I fixed them all now. The lines you mentioned are part of a binding that points to the `DataContext` of a parent element. This `DataContext is expected to be the view model `UsersViewModel`. The corrected path is `Path=DataContext.(UsersViewModel.GenerateFilterViewItemsCommand)` and casts the `DataContext` which is of type `object` to `UsersViewModel` and then references the property `GenerateFilterViewItemsCommand`.

Comment: Can you try `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("I've been triggered")`?

Answer (score 0):

Try The Following :

Give you'r Page or DataGrid a Name, And change your Binding to

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.IncludeCommand, Source={x:Reference myPage}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are autogenerating columns, I strongly suspect it is trying to find a `OpenPopupCommand` in one of the string properties on the items for `FilteredUserList`.

Comment: Think is that i have tried to pass parameter when used not auto generated button, and it worked: i get System.Windows.Controls.Button: 2  -> "2" is button content.  but it is not wroking on buttons are generated with columns...Some thoughts?